# Copying Clipboard Text to ListBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, clipboard

I'm switching from VB.NET to C#.

I'm trying to copy the clipboard content to a `ListBox`.

I use the code below in VB.NET:

```
Dim getClipboard As String() = Split(Clipboard.GetText, vbNewLine)
lstTarget.Items.AddRange(getClipboard)
```

I couldn't find what to use to split `"\n"`.

So far I was able to get clipboard text with

```
(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
```

I tried working with `string[]` and `List<string>` but I messed up with index or lengths and  couldn't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
lstTarget.Items.AddRange(text.Split("\n")));
```

Comment: I was thinking vb way and was trying to do something like split(x,y). Now I see what was I doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You use `.Split()` to split strings

```
Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(line => lstTarget.Items.Add(line));
```

or

```
lstTarget.AddRange(Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the text and add it directly to the list:

```
lstTarget.AddRange(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
                            .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: This is a nice method too, Thank you for responding